# AngularJS filter / add property to object

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects and each object has an email sender property like my `sender{sender@demo.abc}`. Now I want to fill a table with 2 values: 1) name ("my sender") and 2) address ("sender@demo.abc").

Currently I use a filter to add the 2 new properties to my object and render it with an ng-repeat. My problem now is that I get an error

> [$rootScope:infdig]

(but rendering result is fine). I googled a bit and the problem may be that I create a new array in my filter and the property length not match with the ng-repeat object length.

I am new to angularjs and I am not sure if I use the filter totally wrong and there is a much bether way for my wanted solution?

Demo Code JS:

```
demoApp.filter("customFilter", function () {
return function (input) {
    var result = [];
    if (input && input.length && input.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var senderName = "";
            var senderDomain = "";
            var both = input[i].Name;

            both = both.split("").reverse().join("");
            senderName = both.substring(both.indexOf("<") + 1).split("").reverse().join("");
            senderDomain = both.substring(1, both.indexOf("<")).split("").reverse().join("");

            var domainBeforeAt = senderDomain.split("@")[0];
            var domainAfterAt = senderDomain.split("@")[1];

            var output = {
                "customId": i,
                "displayName": senderName,
                "domain": {
                    "full": senderDomain,
                    "beforeAt": domainBeforeAt,
                    "afterAt": domainAfterAt,
                }
            }

            result.push(output);
        }
    }

    return result;        
}
});
```

Demo Code HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="sender in list.Sender | customFilter track by $index">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** In order to meet the requirement of accessing nested objects in the filter, I have changed the way the filter returns output.

```
.filter("customFilter", function () {
  return function (input, params) {
    ...
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var toReturn = output;
    for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
      toReturn = toReturn[args[i]];
    }
    return toReturn;
 };
});
```

Without using eval, to return `output.domain.full`, you'll have to pass in the levels of the nested object as parameters to the filter, e.g.:

```
<td class="col-xs-6">{{sender.Name | customFilter:'domain':'full'}}</td>
```

So, I think your issue stems from the fact that you want to track by $index in your ng-repeat, not in your filter. Once you have set up the `ng-repeat` directive inside your `div`, what you are passing into your filter is each individual sender in your data set, not all of them in an array, so you don't need to run a for loop over the input.

One approach, which I've done in the snippet below, is to pass what parameter you want to display (name, email) into the filter and get that property of the object your filter outputs. Another approach would be to create a separate name and email filter and apply them individually, but you'd be repeating a lot of code that way.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('SenderListCtrl', function() {
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.Sender = [
    {
      Name: "my sender<sender@demo.abc>",
      Age: 21
    },
    {
      Name: "another sender<anothersender@demo.abc>",
      Age: 37
    },
    {
      Name: "yet another sender<yetanothersender@demo.abc>",
      Age: 28
    } 
  ];
})
.filter("customFilter", function () {
  return function (input, params) {
    
    if (input && input.length && input.length > 0) {
      var senderName = "";
      var senderDomain = "";
      var both = input;
      
      senderName = both.substring(0, both.indexOf("<"));
      senderDomain = both.substring(both.indexOf("<")+1,both.indexOf(">"));
 
      var domainBeforeAt = senderDomain.split("@")[0];
      var domainAfterAt = senderDomain.split("@")[1];
      var output = {
        name: senderName,
        email: senderDomain,
        domain: {
          full: senderDomain,
          beforeAt: domainBeforeAt,
          afterAt: domainAfterAt,
        }
      };
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      var toReturn = output;
      for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        toReturn = toReturn[args[i]];
      }
      return toReturn;    
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="bootstrap-js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="SenderListCtrl as list">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-6">Name</th>
          <th class="col-xs-6">Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="sender in list.Sender track by $index">
          <td class="col-xs-6">{{sender.Name | customFilter:'name'}}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-6">{{sender.Name | customFilter:'domain':'full'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that is the right direction - thanks! :) can I use {{sender.Name | customFilter:'domain.full'}} without an eval in my filter? (return eval("output."param);)

Comment: Glad it helped! Please see my update regarding nested parameters.